# Mansion Of Madness- Discarded combat cards specific type of combat(sharp,melee)

Tags: mansions-of-madness

When entering combat and flipping the correct combat decks for the creature type, we have already flipped all of the "sharp melee weapon" cards. I want to attack with the Axe again.

When we reach the bottom of the deck, do we shuffle the cards into the combat card deck or do I need to wait to attack with this weapon until all the combat cards have been flipped and then shuffle the deck?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking here? Have you discarded all the "sharp melee weapons" you're carrying or do you mean that you've used all the "sharp melee weapon" cards in a specific combat deck? If it's the second point, you keep flipping cards until you find one with "sharp melee weapons" on it. If you get through the whole deck and don't find any more, shuffle and start again.

Answer (score 2):

> If a deck of cards runs out, the players shuffle the discard pile to create a new deck.

Source: [Mansions of Madness Core Rulebook](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/ad/39/ad394c78-5b46-494d-a1f2-60776f83038c/mansionsofmadnesslores.pdf), page 25 - "Component Limitations"

Answer (score 0):

You shuffle the deck immediately when you hit the bottom of the deck, then continue flipping as if you never ran out of cards.

Effectively, treat the combat card decks as "infinite". You should never run out of cards, you should always get an effect from the action.